# NSRangeException indexSet count or lastIndex must not exceed -numberOfAssets

Tags: objective-c, nsrangeexception

I have a new Project from an older Member of our Team.
I Don't know where the Problem is...

```
  // Chooses the photo at the last index
    [group enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[group numberOfAssets] - 1] options:0 usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {

        // The end of the enumeration is signaled by asset == nil.
        if (alAsset) {
            ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];
            [defaults setObject:representation.filename forKey:@"latest"];
        }
    }];
} failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
    // Typically you should handle an error more gracefully than this.
    NSLog(@"No groups");
}];
```

2014-09-04 11:37:55.960 IMDropShare[28350:60b] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.06 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: indexSet count or lastIndex must not exceed -numberOfAssets
2014-09-04 11:38:00.980 IMDropShare[28350:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'indexSet count or lastIndex must not exceed -numberOfAssets'

Comment: When `[group numberOfAssets]` is equal to 0, -1 will be converted to a very big unsigned integer value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was, that no photo was in the Library....

For my Problem i add some Photo's and solved it!

Comment: Even though you got it working, this is **not** a solution. (One) solution would be to enclose the enumeration code in an `if` statement and execute only if their are images present in the gallery.